# How to programmatically add #include files into c++ classes for an entire library

Tags: c++, header, dependencies

(As a preface, I realize this is quirky and not a standard c++ practice but it suits my purposes.)

Alright, so I have a C++ library which is basically all header files because it makes heavy use of templates. Almost every header file contains a single class definition ("ButterworthFilter.h", "Interpolator.h", etc.). I want to make it so that there's a second, "stand alone" version of each of these classes, so that they can be easily transported to different project without taking the entire library. So basically the manual version of this would be to go into each header, see the #include dependencies, and then copy/paste those included classes at the top where they are #included in the original file. The problem with this is that this needs to change whenever there's a change made in one of the original files, so it should be done programmatically whenever updates are made. I was thinking to do it with a perl script but that's pretty much bound to fail.

Is there a way to get the compiler to output the entire content of each dependent file or something? For instance I could tell the compiler to output the dependencies of ButterworthFilter.h and it would check the #includes, see that it depends on Filter.h, and output all of Filter.h (plus any of its dependencies recursively).  Better yet would be a program actually made to manipulate libraries like this. I think it would be awesome to have a tool that can generate a standalone version of any useful class buried inside some library.

Anyway I hope this question makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compiler? gcc should have some option for this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the llvm gcc 4.2 on mac. I see that you can use -E to output all the the preprocessing but this adds a lot of overhead that I don't want to copy/paste into the new file. Stuff like std includes and templates and whatnot. I only want it to output any custom class headers from within the library itself (if that makes sense). Thanks.

Comment: I provided the answer with -M and -MF options. I do not have access to gcc compiler right now - but I believe this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the compiler to write the result of preprocessing. Normally, you use the `-E` option to get the result of preprocessing the file. The proprocessed file tends to have line numbers and indications of the original file - you might want to remove these. Of course, this would also expand macros but beyond the include guards you are hopefully not using any macros anyway...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Unfortunately this outputs so much other nonsense that it would be about as difficult to parse as parsing the original file. I tried to find another flag that would eliminate some of the system files and whatnot but it doesn't look like there's anything perfect... http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html I'll keep thinking. Much appreciated Dietmar.

Answer (score 0):

You looked into right direction: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

There is -M option which generates rule suitable for make - so it lists all dependent files - thats is all header files, so make can know that if header changes the object file must be recompiled. Use with -MF option.

From gcc doc:

```
-M
Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable 
for make describing the dependencies of the main source file. 
The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name 
for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included files, 
including those coming from -include or -imacros command line options.
...

This option does not suppress the preprocessor's debug output, such as -dM. 
To avoid mixing such debug output with the dependency rules you should explicitly 
specify the dependency output file with -MF, 
or use an environment variable like DEPENDENCIES_OUTPUT...
```